# How to add multiple TileOverlayOptions to a GoogleMap?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, tile

I am trying to add multiple custom tile providers to a Google map via [`GoogleMap.addTileOverlay()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#addTileOverlay(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.TileOverlayOptions)) as described in the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/tileoverlay).
When I only add one of them - each of them work.

When I add all at once **nothing** is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occured because some members for the multiple instances of my custom `UrlTileProvider` where declared `static`.